# Can one install software on a Virtual Machines(Guest OS)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

If one is using some kind of Virtual Machine(Paid products like Vmware Workstation, Citrix, Microsoft-Hyper-V, or free ones like  VirtualBox) and say for e.g.

The host OS is Windows and Guest OS is some Linux(Ubuntu) can one install software packages in that Ubuntu using the package manager for Ubunut apt-get install

The question hold in general for any Host-Guest OS? Can one install softwares in the Gues OS which is running as a virtual machine/Virtual OS on the Host OS/Platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much so. A VM is basically just an emulated computer at its most basic level, so you can do with it as you would usually do with a normal computer (well, except take it apart of course :) ).

Also, so long as whoever set the VM for you set up permissions right, you will be able to install software using the `sudo apt-get install package`. ;)

Comment: What if the programs you want to install (that are Windows 95 native) require license keys or a Dongle USB key? Will those work, or be recognized, on a VM?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.  The guest VM is a completely independent system from an OS and software perspective.

Comment: +1, the guest is agnostic to whether or not it's virtual or physical.  As long as a repository is configured and there's a network path to the repository virtualization changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install software by copying them into pen drive and get access to it in VirtualBox or VMware. Double click and install it as you normally do in the real OS.

Also, you can share the folders where you downloaded the software and install it normally.